# Credit Card verification in heroku

Tags: heroku

I am trying to create a Twitter bot and I don't have a credit card to verify the Heroku account. Is there any other way to continue with creating my Twitter bot?

I tried the code on my terminal but directs me to the credit card verification page

```
heroku addons:create scheduler:standard
```

I expected direct access after coming all that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not if you need addons. The use of any addon besides Heroku Postgres and Heroku connect [requires account verification](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification#when-is-verification-required):

> You must verify your account if you, or collaborators of your app, want to:
>
> - Use more than one dyno in the app.
> - **Add any add-on to the app, even if the add-on is free. The only exceptions to this are the free plans for the Heroku Postgres and Heroku Connect add-ons, which can be used without verification.**
> - Add a [custom domain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) to the app.
> - Receive the [transfer of an app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/transferring-apps) that has paid resources.
> - Exceed [default one-off dyno limits](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types#concurrent-one-off-dyno-limits) on the app.
> - Have more than 5 apps at a time. Verified accounts may have up to 100 apps.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Chris, you need more than one dyno due to which heroku is requesting to add credit card, but if you don't have credit card, you can add debit card info as well.I am not sure if it works in all countries but i tried with debit card issued from (India - visa/master-card) and it worked for me.

Comment: However there seems to be no list of debit cards that are supported

Comment: There actually is a list

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification#accepted-credit-cards